# My if/else expression is not working I don't know why?

Tags: python, selenium

My code:

```
website = browser.find_element_by_link_text('Website')

if website:
    website.click()
else:
    print('no website')
```

What I am trying to do is click the button if it is available on the page. If the button isn't available I want it to print no website available on the console and proceed to the next step.

I do not know what I am doing wrong does anyone know how to do fix this?

Thanks in advance I am new to coding!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, your code does not allow for reproduction of the problem. Please make sure to provive an [mre] when submitting a question.

Answer (score 0):

Before you find an element, you need first visit a website.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
print('Acessando web site: {}'.format(os.getenv('VISIT_URL')))
driver.get('www.example.com')
#here onwards you can access browser elements like buttons links etc
```

Comment: My code is already on a specific website once it reaches this point of the program. I want it to look for a specific button on the page. If the button doesn't exist instead of the code giving an error I want it to print out website doesn't exist and continue to the next step of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You are giving a instance of Web element to if() condition, where a boolean expression is expected.

1) Try checking the presence first using `find_elements_by_link_text() # _elements_`

```
if len(driver.find_elements_by_link_text('Website')) > 0: 
    driver.find_element_by_id('Website').click()
```

2) Or use expected_conditions to check whether the element is available; [expected_conditions documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions)

3) Or use try/except block;

```
    try:
        website = driver.find_elements_by_link_text('Website')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        # code to execute if the expected element is not available
```